# Multiple instances of a service processing rows from a single table, what's the best way to prevent collision

Tags: database, algorithm

We are trying to build a system with multiple instances of a service on different machines that share the load of processing.

Each of these will check a table, if there are rows to be processed on that table, it will pick the first, mark it processing, then process it, then mark it done. Rinse repeat.

What is the best way to prevent a racing condition where 2 instances A and B do the following

A (1) read the table, finds row 1 to process,
B (1) reads the table, finds row 1 to process,
A (2) marks it row processing
B (2) Marks it row processing

In a single app we could use locks or mutexs.

I can just put A1 and A2 in a single transaction, is it that simple, or is there a better, faster way to do this?

Should I just turn it on it's head so that the steps are:

A (1) Mark the next row as mine to process
A (2) Return it to me for processing.

I figure this has to have been solved many times before, so I'm looking for the "standard" solutions, and if there are more than one, benefits and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are a nice simple answer, with two possible drawbacks:

1) You might want to check with the fine print of your database. Sometimes the default consistency settings don't guarantee absolute consistency in every possible circumstance.

2) Sometimes the pattern of accesses associated with using a database to queue and distribute work is hard on a database that isn't expecting it.

One possibility is to look at reliable message queuing systems, which are seem to pretty good match to what you are looking for - worker machines could just read work from a shared queue. Possible jumping-off points are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm